# T-Annihilator for a vector in $C^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the problem

> Let T be the linear operator on $\mathbb{C}^3$ which is represented in the standard ordered
>   basis by the matrix $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
> 1 & i & 0 \\
> -1 & 2 & -i \\
> 0 & 1 & 1 \end{array} \right)$ .Find the T-annihilator of the vector (1, 0, 0) . Find the T-annihilator of (1, 0, i) .

I have for a definition that the T-annihilator of a vector is $P_\alpha$ the unique monic polynomial which generates the ideal such that $g(T)\alpha = 0$ for g in this ideal.

However I don't see how I'm supposed to find this generator. I'm pretty sure it has to deal with the minimal polynomial of T but I'm stuck after that.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you found the minimal polynomial yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show that the $T$-annihilator divides the minimal polynomial. From that point on, just test the factors of the minimal polynomial to find the one of smallest degree which annihilates the vector.

Comment: So I find the minimal polynomial to be (factored) (x - 1) (x - 1/2 (3 - Sqrt[1 - 8 I])) (x - 1/2 (3 + Sqrt[1 - 8 I])). 3 Distinct roots. And when I look at things that divide this polynomial and annihilate T for the first vector I get the minimal polynomial again (no smaller polynomial seems to work)? Is this correct?

Comment: @AvatarOfChronos I haven't done the problem myself, but the procedure certainly seems right.

Comment: thanks, I think I've got it now.

Answer (score 1):

This works for any operator T and for any finite dimension vector space over any field.
Find the minimum n so that the vectors $a, T(a), T^2(a),..., T^n(a)$ are linearly dependent, of course you need  to choose a not iqual zero. Assume that you have the linear combination
$r_0a+r_1T(a)+...+r_{n-1}T^{n-1}(a)+T^n(a)=0$, then the T-annihilator of a is the polynomial
$r_0+r_1x+...+r_{n-1}x^{n-1}+x^n$.